# C++ multithreading with octave/other matrix library

Tags: c++, multithreading, octave

I'm trying to do some programming that requires a bit of linear algebra, for which I've decided to use Octave C++ API. I was looking online for resources for writing parallel code with the API and was unable to find any. Is there anything to be found? If not, is there an equivalent library that does support it? I don't really want to roll my own thread-safe matrix library.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might want to be more specific - the trivial answer is to not share any data from the library between threads, or only read from shared data between threads.

Comment: Are you looking to do fine-grained, or coarse-grained parallelism?

Comment: You should also clarify if you're using large matrices, or just the small 3x3 or 4x4 matrices used for geometry/graphics.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using fairly large matrices (dimensions in the 100's). Fine-grained parallelism would be what I want since the operations on the matrices are quite trivial. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at ZMQ.  There appears to a bridge between ZMQ and octave as discussed here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/octave-maintainers/2015-01/msg00032.html